# Is it good practice to chain useEffect hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Since there is no setState callback using react hooks I have to use an `useEffect` hook with the state in its dependency array as a callback function for setting the state.

So I often find myself chaining some useEffects to set states, wait until they were set, and then do some actions with it.
This seems not as the correct way for me.

Here is an Example:

```js
const url = useLocation();
 
useEffect(() => {
  // Do some stuff related to URL
  // ...
  // after processing the url params i set a config object as a state
  setConfig();
}, [url.search]);
 
useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch some data with the config 
  // ...
  // after data fetching is done
  setData([]);
}, [config]);
 
useEffect(() => {
  // process my fetched data 
}, [data]);
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: If you're okay with the component re-rendering after each effect step, then sure, that's fine. However, for data fetching you might want to look at SWR or react-query instead.

Comment: And if you don't want that re-rendering and you don't need subsequent steps of the effect cascade to be able to be run independent of the previous steps (i.e. in this case, if you manually modify `config` even if the URL doesn't change), you can run it all in a single effect.

Comment: Will the data be used somewhere and changed thus triggering the useEffect ?

If `config` or `data` will not change anymore, it might be better to put everything in a function and start it in the first useEffect.

You would then chain your promise with `.then()` to act on the data incoming.

Comment: Yes `config` and `data` can be changed later by the users input. Thanks for your answer